# node.js Socket io "Reference error io is not defined"

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I'm working on a chat program, I'm still in the beginning of making it but when I try to connect to the server from the console on google chrome it says  a reference error io is not defined.

client

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>Chat</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="chat">
        <input type="text" class="chat-name" placeholder="Enter your name">
        <div class="chat-messages">
            <div class="chat-message">

            </div>
        </div>
        <textarea placeholder="type your message" class="chat-textarea"></textarea>
        <div class="chat-status">Status: <span>Idle</span></div>
    </div>


    <script>src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"</script>

</body>
</html>
```

server.js

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
client = require('socket.io').listen(8080);
console.log("Server is running on port 8080");
```

Comment: I am not getting variable `io` being used anywhere. is it your full code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because of this:

```
<script>src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"</script>
```

It's a standard JS import. It should look like this:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```